# Making a welcome message an embed on discord.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, bots, embed

I have connected MongoDB to my discord.js code and have made a `setwelcome` command as per-server data so that each server can customize their own welcome message. Everything works great, I just want to know if there is any way that I can make the message appear as an embed? Here's the code:

```
//importing all the needed files and languages
const mongo = require('./mongo')
const command = require('./command')
const welcomeSchema = require('./schemas/welcome-schema')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

//my code is inside this export
module.exports = (client) => {
//this next line is for later
    const cache = {}


    command(client, 'setwelcome', async (message) => {
        const { member, channel, content, guild } = message
//checking to see that only admins can do this
        if (!member.hasPermissions === 'ADMINISTRATOR') {
            channel.send('You do not have the permission to run this command')
            return
        }
//simplifying commands
        let text = content
//this is to store just the command and not the prefix in mongo compass
        const split = text.split(' ')

        if (split.length < 2) {
            channel.send('Please provide a welcome message!')
            return
        }

        split.shift()
        text = split.join(' ')
//this is to not fetch from the database after code ran once
        cache[guild.id] = [channel.id, text]
//this is to store the code inside mongo compass
        await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
            try {
                await welcomeSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                    _id: guild.id
                }, {
                    _id: guild.id,
                    channelId: channel.id,
                    text,
                }, {
                    upsert: true
                })
            } finally {
                mongoose.connection.close()
            }
        })
    })
//this is to fetch from the database
    const onJoin = async (member) => {
        const { guild } = member
        
        let data = cache[guild.id]

        if (!data) {
            console.log('FETCHING FROM DATABASE')
            await mongo().then( async (mongoose) => {
                try {
                    const result = await welcomeSchema.findOne({ _id: guild.id })

                    cache[guild.id] = data = [result.channelId, result.text]
                } finally {
                    mongoose.connection.close()
                }
            })
        }
//this is to simplify into variables
        const channelId = data[0]
        const text = data[1]
/*this is where the message sends on discord. the second of these 2 lines is what I want embedded
which is basically the welcome message itself*/
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.send(text.replace(/<@>/g, `<@${member.id}>`))
    }
//this is to test the command
    command(client, 'simjoin', message => {
        onJoin(message.member)
    })
//this is so the command works when someone joins
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
        onJoin(member)
    })
}
```

I know how to usually make an embed, but I'm just confused at the moment on what to put as `.setDescription()` for the embed.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you just want the set message to just be sent in an embed description instead of plain message content, or do you want the user to be able to customize all of the embed fields?

Comment: Just the message to be sent in an embed description instead of plain message content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have the message be sent as an embed, create a `MessageEmbed` and use `setDescription()` with the description as the only argument. Then send it with `channel.send(embed)`.

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embed.setDescription(text.replace(/<@>/g, `<@${member.id}>`));
channel.send(embed);
```

By the way, if you are confused about how to use a specific method you can always search for the method name on the official [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org) so you don’t have to wait for an answer here. Good luck creating your bot!

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks so simple and now that I've got the answer it just makes so much sense, but again, after coding for like 2 hours non-stop, you start to forget the basics. Thanks again!